# Hbase HRegionServer getting OutOfMemory Error

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

When loading 16 GB data using pig store command into Hbase, the HRegionserver gets killed. It throws OutofMemory error.

PFA the screen shot of the Hbase logs​. We're using 4 datanodes of 12GB RAM each. Any pointers to resolve the issue.

Tried increasing HBASE_HEAPSIZE to 4GB in Hbase-env.sh without any success.

Comment: I can't see any attached log screen shots and that is good. Do not provide pictures of textual information. Also, you are not wondering why a 4GB server cannot handle 16GB data, are you?

Comment: @Yunnosch I've 12GB ram servers. Heap size is of 4GB. Also I'm storing 16GB data using PIG Store command wch invokes mapreduce. So i guess it should be using disk I/O and not the RAM intensive. I've 1 TB hard disks in all the datanodes.